# Fix huge Zoom UI buttons

Tags: zoom-meeting

Whenever I open the Zoom video conference client (v5.1.4. on Ubuntu 20) all UI elements (buttons, text, etc.) are huge compared to those in any other program.

How can I change this? I cannot find anything in the settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Zoom automatically adjusts the size of the UI elements. If your Zoom has very large buttons, it probably detects your screen resolution wrong. This can be the case in multi screen environments or high resolution screens. In this case you can disable the automatic scaling in the config (though afaik not from the GUI) and set a specific scale factor instead:

- exit Zoom (i.e. close everything, including the tray button)
- open `~/.config/zoomus.conf`
- change the `autoScale` setting to `autoScale=false`
- (optionally) change the setting for `scaleFactor`. Small buttons would for instance be displayed with `scaleFactor=1`, bigger ones with `scaleFactor=2`.
- restart Zoom. The settings should then take effect.